# Docker Volume vs AWS s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, docker-volume

Probably I am completely off in my assumptions but I am pretty new to both Docker and Aws and we have two applications which are `Dockerized containers working under the same docker-compose network bridge`.

Now, We have been looking for a way that these two containers can share some files. Since we are on the cloud, one suggestion was Amazon s3 Bucket. Which is great. But My questions is that since we are on Docker envionment does it not make more sense to share those files in a Docker Volume? I thought that's exactly what Docker Volume is. A mounted virtual place where files can be shared. At least that is my shallow and simplistic understanding after reading about Docker Volumes

So I do have some questions

1. Is my assumptions that `AWS s3 bucket` and `Docker volumes` provide similar functionality  like comparing apples to apples?
2. If my assumption is correct then would a `Docker Volume` qualify to be called an object store?
3. If it does qualify to be called an object store then would it be wise to use `Docker Volume` as replacement of AWS s3?
4. If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. They are different and even complementary.  There's a plugin for Docker volumes on AWS here:
   https://github.com/joeduffy/blocker
2. I wouldn't use the term *object store*.  It's implemented as a filesystem mounted on the container.
3. No...
4. ... for the reason stated in (1).